# Checking all items in a list simultaneously in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a "flock" of "boids" and during the initial creation of the boids they must not be created over an obstacle. However they must still be created randomly, as are the obstacles.

So I have created them randomly and then check their locations and correct them if needed. This seems to work most of the time but I think what is happening is that if Boid 1 is placed on obstacle 1 it is moved off of obstacle 1 however it might land on obstacle 2. Well when it is moved it may be moved back onto obstacle 1 which is not check again. How can I stop this from happening?

Here is the creation code:

```
 def create_boids(self):
    for boid in range(self.flock_number):  # add the specified number of boids to our flock within our screen's region.
        self.boids.append(Boid(random.randint(self.region[0], self.region[2]), random.randint(self.region[1], self.region[3])))

    for boid in self.boids:  # adjust our boids so they are not created on top of an obstacle and are within our screen's region.
        for obstacle in self.obstacles:
                while colliding(boid.pos[0], boid.pos[1], boid.radius, obstacle[0][0], obstacle[0][1], obstacle[1]):
                    boid.pos[0] = random.randint(self.region[0], self.region[2])
                    boid.pos[1] = random.randint(self.region[1], self.region[3])

self.region = (x, y, width, height)  
obstacle in self.obstacles = ((x, y), radius)
```

Here is collision check also.

```
def colliding(c1x, c1y, c1r, c2x, c2y, c2r):
    if (int(c1x) - int(c2x)) ** 2 + (int(c1y) - int(c2y)) ** 2 <= (int(c1r) + int(c2r)) ** 2:
        return True
    return False
```

I'm not sure what to try here. Thanks for any help that comes my way!

Comment: Can two boids be in the same spot?

Comment: When you move a boid, start checking from the beginning again?

Comment: The title is misleading; to me "simultaneous" suggests concurrent. All code so far is sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a function which checks if the boid is colliding with *any* obstacle... and keep picking a new position for as long as it is:

```
def is_boid_colliding_with_obstacles(self, boid):
    return any(colliding(boid.pos[0], boid.pos[1], boid.radius, 
                         obstacle[0][0], obstacle[0][1], obstacle[1]) 
               for obstacle in self.obstacles)

def create_boids(self):
    for boid in range(self.flock_number):  # add the specified number of boids to our flock within our screen's region.
        self.boids.append(Boid(random.randint(self.region[0], self.region[2]), random.randint(self.region[1], self.region[3])))

    for boid in self.boids:  # adjust our boids so they are not created on top of an obstacle and are within our screen's region.
        while self.is_boid_colliding_with_obstacles(boid):
            boid.pos[0] = random.randint(self.region[0], self.region[2])
            boid.pos[1] = random.randint(self.region[1], self.region[3])
```

Or, even better, only generate valid boids in the first place:

```
def is_boid_colliding_with_obstacles(self, boid):
    return any(colliding(boid.pos[0], boid.pos[1], boid.radius, 
                         obstacle[0][0], obstacle[0][1], obstacle[1]) 
               for obstacle in self.obstacles)

def create_boid(self):
    while True:
        boid = Boid(random.randint(self.region[0], self.region[2]), 
                    random.randint(self.region[1], self.region[3]))
        if not self.is_boid_colliding_with_obstacles(boid):
            return boid

def create_boids(self):
    self.boids.extend(self.create_boid() for _ in range(self.flock_number))
```

Comment: oh, I did not understand the use of any() when I tried using that earlier. Thanks I will try this.

Comment: @DaltonFox: Sure. It's just a more concise way of looping through all the obstacles and returning `True` if any of the calls to `colliding(...)` return `True`.

Comment: the first solution worked, I will stick with it although I will study your second example so I understand it. Thanks again